# React - this.input.value vs handle change

Tags: reactjs

What is better?

I have a form with 10 inputs.

Should I use `this.input.value` or handle change and store it in `state`?

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({input: e.target.value});
}
...
<input type="text" value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

or

```
onSubmit() {
    const inputValue = this.input.value;
    ...
}
...
<input type="text" ref={(input) => {this.input = input;}} />
```

From the documentation:

> When to Use Refs
>
> ```
> There are a few good use cases for refs:
>
>     Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
>     Triggering imperative animations.
>     Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.
>
> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.
> ```

Comment: First off, `this.input.value` wouldn't work. You need to reference the input box using `this.refs`. I would use state to avoid complexity

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve: are there actions that should occur on a per-input basis, or do you only act on form submission, once all values have been submitted?

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy, the second one.

Comment: Well, then you need neither. On submission, just collect all values from all fields and act on them (i.e. post to server, save to local state, save to localDB - whatever you need.) You can get the values by name or id.

Comment: @VamshiGudipati actually that does work. He's using a ref callback instead of string refs. String refs in React have been deprecated and shouldn't be used. `this.refs` shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting up controlled inputs is kind of a pain, but I use this pattern to make it a little easier.

Create one onChange event handler for ALL inputs:

```
handleInputChange(e){
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}
```

Then, for your inputs, be sure to give it a `name` that matches a key in your state to update.

```
render() {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, acceptTerms } = this.state;
    return (
        <form>
            <input name="firstName" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={firstName} />
            <input name="lastName" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={lastName} />
            <input name="email" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={email} />
            <input type="checkbox" name="acceptTerms" onChange={this.handleInputChange} checked={acceptTerms} />
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking about converting it to a HOC though. Haven't experimented with it too much yet.

Comment: Yeah, looks good. In my real projects I do `onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(null, 'name')}` and `handleInputChange(inputName, e) { this.setState({[inputName]: e.target.value }) }`. Your code looks better. But I see a lot of `this.input.value` in examples and wondering if I can use it.

Comment: Maybe I should ask `Why not this.input.value` instead of `What is better`.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda: I don't see setState changing the state value or re-rendering the dom here. Am i missing something here?

Comment: @Mad-D State gets updated in `handleInputChange`. It uses the inputs `name` attrib to know which piece of state to update.

Comment: @Nick Yeah I think so. "Better" usually refers to best practice, that's why I suggested the controlled inputs method. Really either way works just fine and it's up to personal preference. I like to make sure that all of my forms behave the same way, so just pick one and stick to it!

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda: I liked the idea and was playing around but i don't see state values changing. I added `<div> You added : <code>{this.state.firstName}</code></div>` after form element and state value didn't change.

Comment: @Mad-D Hmm, weird. Might be something in your setup? I've recreated the functionality in a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/560fyjnp/438/).

Comment: @Mad-D, should work. http://jsfiddle.net/560fyjnp/439/. Did you bind `this`? `this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)`.